# How to make Column Dynamic in below mentioned VBA

Tags: vba

```
If Worksheets("Data").Range("D5").value = 0 Then
Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
```

Sir, I have the above code where Column "K" is hide/unhide based on the cell "D5" of another sheet. But when I Add or Delete Column in my excel then my desired column no. shift to "L" or "J" but column "K" static in VBA and hide by this code which should not happen. How this column "K" automatically change when a column delete or add in excel

Comment: Do you have any header in column K?

Comment: Yes, like "Homeloan"

Comment: You cant prevent it from shifting the other columns left once you delete a column. Instead of deleting the column you want, instead try clearing it using `Columns("...").Clear`

Comment: The more context you give us, the more relevant our answers will be. When would you like this code to execute, when this sheet is activated? Is the data in this sheet in a table (aka ListObject, which you can create with `Insert` > `table`)? If not, can you change that?

Comment: Sorry i could't get it completely. Actually my table has many column and it have to add or delete some column if that product not available so my desired column "Homeloan" which is "K" shift frequently but i want to hide this Homeloan column irrespective of its column Number like K, L, J whatever its current column number. It should do if i can name entire column but its not working

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()     
    If Worksheets("Data").Range("D5").value = 0 Then    
    Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True    
    Else    
    Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False    
    End If    
    End sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you put a name ("Named Range") to the top cell of the column you want to show/hide. Then you can access this named Range in the code.

Assuming you defined the name `"Homeloan"` on Cell `K1`: write

```
Range("HomeLoan").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

*Note that you should always qualify the Excel objects so that it is clear which worksheet you want to access, but that's not part of your question*

Comment: Thanks sir, You solution is simple and work great, thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have problem to unhide all the columns before searching for the word "Homeloan" this should work even if you delete or add columns.

```
Sub test()

Dim lcol As Long
With Worksheets("Data")
    .Columns("A:AC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide all the columns first

    'This only works if the column with the word homeloan is not hidden.
    lcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Homeloan", .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)), 0) 'Find last column in row 1. Then create a range to look for the word "Homeloan". Last, return the current column number where Header "Homeloan" exists.
        If .Range("D5").Value = 0 Then
            .Columns(lcol).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            .Columns(lcol).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
End With
End Sub
```